# How to add more objects to an animation group?

Tags: animation, collections, groups

I'm new to animating in Blender. The issue is I've created a simple space ship object and animated it. Working great! I then used Random Flow mesh generator (great 3rd party addon!) to create additional layered objects from the simple space ship object. The issue is that those new layered objects, e.g., **Front.001_RExtr**, are outside the group **Space Ship Animated**, but they need to be included in that group.

**Question: Is there way to add those new objects to the group Space Ship Animated?**

Thanks. Blender 2.93.5 under Windows 10.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: `Space Ship Animated` is the parent of an empty and several meshes such as `Front` and `Rear`.  You can also parent the circled meshes to it and they will move with it in the animation.  1) Deselect everything.  2) Select all of the circled meshes.  3) Select `Space Ship Animated` . 4) Type CTRL-P.  5) Select Object from the drop down.  The circled meshes will now move with `Space Ship Animated` in the animation.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you Marty Fouts. That works! :)